# Network adapter on HP laptop vs USB network adapter

Tags: networking, adapter

I see that similar issues to what I am experiencing are covered in other posts, but this is more like a follow up to those issues. I too am experiencing MANY events where the network adapter on my HP suddenly doesn't work. The work-around has been to disable and re-enable it on Device Manager.
Based on what I have read here it seems that I may be best served by a USB Network Adapter. I am curious if that will stop my issues or will the potentially poor internal adapter "overpower" the usb?

Thanks!

Comment: What “similar issues”?

Comment: Oops...I meant that I keep having to disable and re-enable the Network Adapter as it keeps "shutting off"  thx!

Comment: Have you tried a USB NIC? It seems you can answer your own question by trying this, it is a good suggestion. I don't know what you mean by "over power". Devices don't over power each other on your computer.